# New Google Cloud Console not showing TEXT field

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console

In new Developer Console TEXT field are not shown, I can see only an empty JSON Object; instead in the old one is possible to see part of the content.

Maybe I have to attach a property or an annotation to allow the visualization in the Datastore Viewer of TEXT fields?

Also, if I enter in the Edit section of the Entity, I can't see any kind associated to that field, it only shows the message "Editing is not supported for this type"; so it seems that the type of the field is well recognized...

Anybody knows if this is a bug or an expected behaviour of the new console?

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bug to me. I tried with my python application and i got the same issue. I think its better if you raise this defect on public Issue Tracker of Google. Find the [link](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/) of PIT and i will also star this issue so that they will try to resolve this issue ASAP.

Comment: I've open the issue.
[link](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11787&thanks=11787&ts=1426493427)
I hope they'll gonna fix it asap.

Answer (score 0):

This was missing feature when the new console rolled out. Support for the all property types has since been made publicly available as an advanced edit mode.

[image: Image of Text property]

---

You'll also notice there's now the ability to enter an advanced editor view for more complex property types.

[image: Image of editing an embedded entity]